# Using innerHTML within onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a button that, when clicked, creates HTML elements beside it with different numbers.
The onclick function only runs once when clicked. I need to be able to click the button and fire the function multiple times. Here's my code:

HTML

```js
var saveHTML = document.getElementById('save');
var saveContainerHTML = document.getElementById("save-container");
var counter = 0;

saveHTML.onclick = function() {
  counter++;
  console.log("Save pressed");
  saveContainerHTML.innerHTML += (counter);
};
```

```html
<div id="save-container">
  <button id="save"> save </button>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g381ubfL/

Note that removing `saveContainerHTML.innerHTML += (counter);` allows the function to fire multiple times as intended, whereas leaving it in only allows it to fire once.

The function works when using `onclick="myFunction()"` within the HTML itself, but that is not an option for the project I'm working on. I'm also not using jQuery, and I would like to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: It seems that you destroy the element inside of save-container. thats why it is only triggering once

Comment: Best practice would be to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than setting the on-click.

Comment: I would include an additional span adjacent to your button and update its html, rather than the entire save container's html.